# Django Microsoft Authentication

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to include in my Django website the possibility to sign in using a Microsoft login.

I have set up a new App registration and included the below as redirect urls.

[image]

I then followed this set of instruction in my Django site:

https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

The Code is as follows:
settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    'django.contrib.sites',
    'microsoft_auth',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = ''

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'microsoft_auth.context_processors.microsoft',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = ''


Database
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_SIZE = [1920, 1080]
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_QUALITY = 75
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_KEEP_META = True
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_FORCE_FORMAT = 'JPEG'
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_FORMAT_EXTENSIONS = {'JPEG': ".jpg"}
DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_NORMALIZE_ROTATION = True


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'microsoft_auth.backends.MicrosoftAuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' # if you also want to use Django's authentication
    # I recommend keeping this with at least one database superuser in case of unable to use others
]
# values you got from step 2 from your Mirosoft app
MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_ID = ''
#MICROSOFT_AUTH_TENANT_ID = ''
MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET = ''
MICROSOFT_AUTH_LOGIN_TYPE = 'ma'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/site/wwwroot/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'

SITE_ID = 1
```

In urls.py I've included this line

```
path('microsoft/', include('microsoft_auth.urls', namespace='microsoft')),
```

However when trying to access the admin module and click Microsoft, I'm getting this error.

[image]

django version: 3.0.4
python version: 3.8.5

Comment: Can you include some code so we can debug it?

Comment: Modified the question and included the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was that i did not change the localhost in my sites model. As soon as I have implemented that change the issue was sorted.

Comment: Where did you make this? Please write.

Comment: Where you change the localhost in the sites view? please be more specific